# Use of "in dem" versus "im"

Tags: preposition

Here are two German sentences from the Duo language-learning app:

1. Die Fahrkarten sind **im** Reisezentrum = The tickets are in the travel center
2. Es gibt acht Restaurants **in dem** Stadtviertel =There are eight restaurants in the neighborhood

**Question:** What is the German grammar rule on the use of **"in dem**" versus **"im"**? If possible, please provide an authoritative source for an explanation of the rule.

Answer (score 3):

If a possible contraction isn't used that means the article is meant as a demonstrative. A pointing finger.

> Es gibt acht Restaurants **in dem** Stadtviertel.
> — There are eight restaurants **in that** neighborhood.

Answer (score 2):

The reason "im" is used in your example is that both parties know about *which* Reisezentrum is meant already.

You can find a full list of reasons to use a contraction in Duden Grammar at Randnummer 925.